# Layer SRS WKT: unknown, shapefile created with pyshp and python

Tags: python, coordinate-system, shapefile, convert, csv

**The problem is solved with a proj file**.
I created a shapefile from a csv file. I used ogrinfo and appears Layer SRS WKT: unknown.

## Technologies

- Python 2.7.9
- [pyshp](https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp) compatible with Python 2.7
- proj 4.8.0, 6 March 2012
- geos 3.4.2
- gdal
- django 1.11 and GeoDjango

## Sample of the csv file

```
Name;Latitude;Longitude;
ALAVA SALIDAS;42.842003;-2.740091
TIPSA FUENLABRADA LLEGADAS;40.266063;-3.848882
```

## Python code

import shapefile as shp
import csv, sys

```
class convertCsvToShp:
def __init__(self, csv_path):
    self.csv_path=csv_path

# funtion to generate a .prj file
def getWKT_PRJ (self, epsg_code):
    import urllib
    wkt = urllib.urlopen("http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/{0}/prettywkt/".format(epsg_code))
    remove_spaces = wkt.read().replace(" ","")
    output = remove_spaces.replace("\n", "")
    return output

def code(self):

    try:
        # Set shapefile writer

        w = shp.Writer()
        w.autoBalance = 1

        # Fields are the city, the latitude and the longitude.
        w.field("name", "C", 50) # C are ASCII characters.
        w.field("latitude", "F", 10, 6)
        w.field("longitude", "F", 10, 6)

        # Readeing data from csv file
        with open(self.csv_path + 'coord.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
            next (reader, None) # Skip the header of the csv

            for row in reader:
                # Create the point of the geometry
                w.point(float(row[1]), float(row[2]))
                # Attributes of the data
                w.record(row[0], row[1], row[2])

        w.save(self.csv_path + 'agencies')

        # create a projection file
        prj = open(self.csv_route + 'agencies.prj', 'w')
        epsg = self.getWKT_PRJ("4326")
        prj.write(epsg)
        prj.close()
        return True
    except:
        print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
        raise
```

## ogrinfo

ogrinfo -so csvtoshp/static/files/agencies.shp agencies

[image]

## Problem

The problem is that openlayers do not show the coordinates correctly. I do not know that this Layers SRS WKT unknown is involved.
**It is required a proj file?** Yes, it is required it.

## New ogrinfo

[image]

Comment: see Pyshp: [Create a .prj Projection File for a Shapefile](http://geospatialpython.com/2011/02/create-prj-projection-file-for.html) or use another module as [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/) or [GeoPandas](http://geopandas.org/)

Comment: Ok, thanks you very much. In consideration of your advice, I created prj file in my code. The ogrinfo works. I am going to write my solution.

Comment: I wrote the solution. A function getWKT_PRJ (self, epsg_code) to take epsg_code and the creation of the prj inside the function code.I decided to use leaflet and leave openalayers. It is not fixed muy problem with the coordinates of the map. I will put another posts. The issue of this post is fixed.

Comment: Please self-answer your question in the answer section below.